# Php putenv() question

Tags: php

I am new to php. Can anyone give a good definition or example when to use putenv() in php? Thanks.

Comment: The definition is in [the PHP docs](http://us.php.net/putenv).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The putenv function inside of PHP is used to set an environment variable inside the $_ENV[] global array. check out the php manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Hope that helps,
RayQuang

Comment: Note for other people coming across this - putenv() is a DIFFERENT STORE than the $_ENV[] superglobal.  putenv('FOO') !== $_ENV['FOO'].